# Yosemite 10.10.3 install Bower and Grunt ERROR

Tags: terminal, gruntjs, bower-install

I've just updated to Yosemite 10.10.3 and tried to install Bower and Grunt, both when installing give me errors. I did overpass this error by using sudo before the install command but as soon as checking the version this is what the return message is: `-bash: bower: command not found` after a search did an `echo $PATH` that resulted as: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Is there a solution to this? I've been looking around the web trying everything the i could find but haven't found a work around it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Bower Error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /Users/albertoc/.node/bin/bower
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/bower'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/bower' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/bower'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/bower']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/bower' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/albertoc/npm-debug.log
```

Grunt Error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /Users/albertoc/.node/bin/grunt
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/grunt'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/grunt']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/grunt' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/grunt'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/grunt']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/albertoc/.node/bin/grunt' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/albertoc/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, updating to node v0.12.3 with the pkg installer from https://nodejs.org/download/ and running the command with sudo fixed it for me.

Hope it helps.
Cheers